# Install urlgabber module for python3?

Tags: drivers, package-management, python, python3

As far as I can tell, only the package `python-urlgrabber` is available, which on Ubuntu means the python 2.7 module. This is confirmed when python3 cannot find the module but `2.7` successfully imports it.

`pip3` cannot locate the package, and `apt-cache search` returns only the above package.

I'm aware it is a relatively outdated package, but for various reasons I need to use it. Is there a python3 version available from a third party repository or will I need to build from source?